# Wasted exponent bit in C# double representation

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, precision

I've been doing research on floating-point doubles in .NET lately. While reading Jon Skeet's article [Binary floating points and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx), I had a question.

Let's start with the example of `46.428292315077` in the article.

Represented as a 64 bit double, this equates to the following bits:

```
Sign   Exponent       Mantissa
0      10000000100    0111001101101101001001001000010101110011000100100011
```

One bit is used to represent the sign, 11 bits are used to represent the exponent, and 52 bits are used to represent the [mantissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand). Note the bias of 1023 for doubles (which I assume is to allow for negative exponents - more on this later).

My confusion is with the 11 bits which represent the exponent, and their use (or lack thereof) for large numbers, specifically `double.MaxValue` (`1.7976931348623157E+308`).

For the exponent, there are a few special values as cited in the article which help determine a number's value. All zeroes represent 0; all ones represent NaN and positive/negative infinity. There are 11 bits to work with: the first bit of the exponent is bias, so we can disregard that. This gives us 10 bits which control the actual size of the exponent.

The exponent on `double.MaxValue` is 308, which can be represented with 9 bits (`100110100`, or with bias: `10100110100`). The smallest fractional value is `double.Epsilon` (`4.94065645841247E-324`), and its exponent can still be represented in 9 bits (`101000100`, or with bias: `00101000100`).

You might notice that the first bit after the bias always seems to be wasted. Are my assumptions about negative exponents correct? If so, why is the second bit after the bias wasted? Regardless, it seems like the *actual* largest number we could represent (while respecting the special values and a possible sign bit after the bias) is `111111111` (or `511` in base 10).

If the bit after the bias is actually wasted, why can't we represent numbers with exponents larger than 324? What am I misunderstanding about this?

Comment: "the first bit of the exponent is bias, so we can disregard that" -- I have no idea whatsoever what this sentence means, and it is the crux of your argument.  The first bit of the exponent is the first bit of the exponent. Can you explain in more detail what you mean here?  There are an *enormous* number of doubles that have the second high bit of the exponent on; why do you think there aren't?  I can't make heads nor tails of this question.

Comment: @EricLippert see the second paragraph under the heading "What exactly does a floating point number look like in memory?" According to Jon Skeet, the exponent is biased by 1023, so `10000000100` is actually 1028-1023, so its exponent is 5.

Comment: That's correct. So what does "the first bit is bias" mean?  And why is the second bit not possibly 1? Suppose the exponent was `11000000100`; what would that be, unbiased?

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake, I understand your confusion.  **The exponent is a power of two, not a power of ten**.  Your math is assuming that it is a power of ten. That's completely wrong.

Comment: @EricLippert 516 as I understand it, in base 10.

Comment: This is the difference between *double* and *decimal*. In *double*, the exponent is a power of two.  In *decimal*, the exponent is a power of ten.  *That's why we need two different types*.

Comment: Now, there *are* wasted bits in *decimal*. A decimal is 128 bits, but 26 of them are required to be zero.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are no wasted bits in a double.

Let's sort out your confusion.  How do we turn a double from bits into a mathematical value?  Let's assume the double is not zero, infinity, negative infinity, NaN or a denormal, because those all have special rules.

The crux of your confusion is mixing up decimal quantities with binary quantities. For this answer I'll put all binary quantities in `this formatting` and decimal quantities in regular formatting.

We take the 52 bits of the mantissa and we put them *after* `1.`  So in your example, that would be

```
1.0111001101101101001001001000010101110011000100100011
```

That's a *binary number*.  So 1 + 0/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 0/32 ...

Then we take the 11 bits of the exponent, treat that as an 11 bit unsigned integer, and subtract 1023 from that value.  So in your example we have `10000000100` which is the unsigned integer 1028. Subtract 1023, and we get 5.

Now we shift the "decimal place" (ha ha) by 5 places:

```
101110.01101101101001001001000010101110011000100100011
```

Note that this is equivalent to multiplying by 2<sup>5</sup>.  **It is not multiplying by 10<sup>5</sup>**!

And now we multiply the whole thing by 1 if the sign bit is `0`, and -1 if the sign bit is `1`.  So the final answer is

```
101110.01101101101001001001000010101110011000100100011
```

Let's see an example with a negative exponent.

Suppose the exponent had been `01111111100`.  That's 1020 as an unsigned integer. Subtract 1023. We get -3, so we would shift three places to the left, and get:

```
0.0010111001101101101001001001000010101110011000100100011
```

Let's see an example with a large exponent. What if the exponent had been `11111111100` ?

Work it out. That's 2044 in decimal. Subtract 1023. That's 1021. So this number would be the extremely large number that you get when multiplying `1.0111001101101101001001001000010101110011000100100011` by 2<sup>1021</sup>.

So the value of that double is **exactly equal to**

32603055608669827528875188998863283395233949199438288081243712122350844851941321466156747022359800582932574058697506453751658312301708309704448596122037141141297743099124156580613023692715652869864010740666615694378079258090383719888417882332809291228958035810952632190230935024250237637887765563383983636480

Which is approximately 3.26030556 x 10<sup>307</sup>.

Is that now clear?

---

If this subject interests you, here's some further reading:

Code to decode a double into its parts:

https://ericlippert.com/2015/11/30/the-dedoublifier-part-one/

A simple arbitrary-precision rational:

https://ericlippert.com/2015/12/03/the-dedoublifier-part-two/

Code to turn a double into its exact rational:

https://ericlippert.com/2015/12/07/the-dedoublifier-part-three/

Representation of floats:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2005/01/10/floating-point-arithmetic-part-one/

How Benford's Law is used to minimize representation errors:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2005/01/13/floating-point-and-benfords-law-part-two/

What algorithm do we use to display floats as decimal quantities?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2005/01/17/fun-with-floating-point-arithmetic-part-three/

What happens when you try to compare for equality floats of different precision levels?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2005/01/18/fun-with-floating-point-arithmetic-part-four/

What properties of standard arithmetic fail to hold in floating point?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2005/01/20/fun-with-floating-point-arithmetic-part-five/

How are infinities and divisions by zero represented?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/15/as-timeless-as-infinity/

Comment: Thanks for the information. I guess my confusion is: what if the decimal were `11111111100`? What is preventing that number from being stored as the exponent?

Comment: @johnnyRose: Nothing prevents that number from being stored as the exponent. That's a perfectly legal exponent.  I'll work out the math for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is _much_ clearer to me after the last example.

Comment: @johnnyRose: You're welcome. The key thing to remember is that doubles are just a fancy way of writing an integer with a power of two after it. Decimals are just a fancy way of writing an integer with a power of ten after it.